# Redirecting servlet to another html page

Tags: java, html, xml, servlets, mapping

I have two html pages - one for login and one that takes in a persons details. The login page is the first page and when the database is checked for the username and password, the user is allowed to enter their details. The SQL code works perfectly, it is just a problem with the mapping I am having. I am using the Tomcat server by the way. Could anybody help or spot what i am doing wrong?

This is my java code for logging in and entering details

```
public class Details extends HttpServlet {

private Connection con;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

  res.setContentType("text/html");
  //return writer
  PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();   

  String username = req.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");

  out.close();

  try {
    login(username, password);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  res.sendRedirect("/redirect.html"); 

   String name = request.getParameter("name");
   String address = request.getParameter("address");
   String age = request.getParameter("age");

    out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Personnel Details</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>");
    out.println(name + address + age);
    out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    System.out.println("Finished Processing");
}

out.close();


}
```

In my web.xml file I have:

```
<web-app>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Details</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Details</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Details</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Details</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/redirect</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Can you tell, what is the location of your redirect.html page.

Comment: @amit4497 redirect.html is in the same location as index.html -C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\webapps\details

Answer (score 9):

You may try this :

```
response.sendRedirect("redirect.html");
```

or

```
response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", "redirect.html");
```

Alternative way,

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
sc.getRequestDispatcher("/redirect.html").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirect to HTML

```
RequestDispatcher ds = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
ds.include(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`1.response.sendRedirect("redirect.html")`   or

```
2.String path= "/redirect";

RequestDispatcher dispatcher =servletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path);

dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```